# Expandable and Collapsible TextView with Ellipsis in a RecyclerView's CardView

Tags: firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview, textview, android-cardview

What is an optimal way to expand and collapse a **TextView with ellipses** in a **RecyclerView's CardView** programmatically?

For example: *"...See more"*

I was looking for some guides about how to make a functional expandable and collapsible "...See more" or "Continue Reading" features but I wasn't satisfied with most of them so I came up with my own and I'd like to share it with everyone especially those who use **Firebase Recycler Adapter** to display their data. Hope this helps someone who is undergoing the same problem I went through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to do is to set your **CardView's height** to `wrap_content`. 
 Everything else after that will be done programmatically using **Java**.

Next, you place this method inside your ViewHolder that extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`:

```
 private void Ellipsize(boolean activate, TextView textView){

        if (activate) {
            textView.setSingleLine(true);
            textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        }
        else{
            textView.setSingleLine(false);
            textView.setEllipsize(null);
        }
    }
```

Call the `Ellipsize(boolean activate, TextView textView);` and pass in the necessary arguments. Pass in `true` and `your_long_text_view` to give it an ellipsis.

```
void setText(String text){
        TextView textTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TEXTVIEW_ID);
        textTV.setText(text);
        Ellipsize(true, textTV);
    }
```

To give your TextView an Expand and Collapse functionality, add this method in your ViewHolder: 
The boolean value of `isExpanded` is `false` and is declared globally.

```
    private void ExpandCollapse(final TextView textView, final View view){

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isExpanded) {
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) view.getRootView(), new AutoTransition());
                    Ellipsize(false, textView);
                }
                else{
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) view.getRootView(), new AutoTransition());
                    Ellipsize(true, textView);
                }
                isExpanded = !isExpanded;
            }
        });

    }
```

After adding all the necessary methods, call them in your `onBindViewHolder` and pass in your TextView that is declared globally in your ViewHolder class as well as your `itemView`

```
 @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Model model) {
            holder.setText(model.getText());
            holder.ExpandCollapse(holder.textTV, holder.itemView);

        }
```